# Limpiar caja de texto vb6

Tags: vb6

Estoy usando `vb6` y quiero que se limpie la caja de texto luego de ingresar un valor alfabético. Lo hice así:

```
Private Sub txtDNI_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
    
    If KeyAscii >= 48 And KeyAscii <= 57 Or KeyAscii = 127 Or KeyAscii = 8 Then
        ' El 48 es 0 y el 57 es 9, 127 es SUPR y 8 es Backspace
    ElseIf KeyAscii = 13 Then
            btnBuscar.SetFocus
    Else
        txtDNI.Text = ""
        MsgBox "Sólo se aceptan números."
        txtDNI.SetFocus
    End If
End Sub
```

Como ven, quiero que en el `textbox` sean solo números. Si son letras, quiero que salga el `MSgBox` del error y que me limpie el `textbox` pero no funciona tan bien.
Pues si ingreso cualquier letra alfabética por ejemplo la letra **a**, me sale el error pero no limpia la caja. Luego de salir del `MsgBox` me sale la letra **a**  en el `textbox`. ¿En dónde estoy errando en el código?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes intentar lo siguiente:

module:

```
Public Sub ClearText(tb as TextBox)
   tb.text=""
End Sub
```

form1:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Call ClearText(text1) ' assuming text1 is your form's textbox name
End Sub
```

Para un formulario con más de un control de cuadro de texto, puede repetir:

```
   Private Sub Command1_Click()
    For Each cControl In Me.Controls
       If (TypeOf cControl Is TextBox) Then
          Call ClearText(cControl)
       End If
    Next
   End Sub
```

solo adaptarlo a tu necesidad a mi me funciono.